# Book about Asperger's for Asperger's

Tags: reference-request, autism, aspergers

Is there a book that people with Asperger's can read to better understand their diagnosis and how to cooperate with people?

Comment: From a non-technical point of view, I think that [The Curious Incident of the Dog in the Night-Time](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1618.The_Curious_Incident_of_the_Dog_in_the_Night_Time) is an excellent place to start, for this with Asperger's and those without.

Answer (score 4):

Aspergers as a diagnosis is no more its been merged into autism spectrum disorder. Its really not that bad of a diagnosis compared to full blown Autism or something like Schizo, Bipolar or BPD.

Here are some books and resources:

[ASD Me Learning Functioning Spectrum](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0983638802)

[Autism Spectrum Disorders: Foundations, Characteristics, and Effective Strategies](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0205545750)

[Ten Things Every Child with Autism Wishes You Knew: Updated and Expanded Edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DUFO4QI)

[Asperger's From Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asperger_syndrome)

I can speak from personal experience the therapies for AS listed on wiki sometimes really work; CBT and anxiety medication really helped me. My brain kinda adapted to the anti-depressant though and I haven't found or really needed anything anxiety in a few months. You'll find social skills like cooperation are this wonderful thing you can practice online with friends and if you mess it up they will be really kind and understanding. I really fail when interacting with [frenemies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenemy).

I have fun talking to people at [Wrong Planet](http://www.wrongplanet.net/) (an autism community) as well. Some people there are less functioning than AS so you have to have compassion and understanding. Others still are higher functioning than me which of course makes me a little jealous but I've learned that I'm not alone and neither are you.